How to move add the cart below quantity in product page in woocommerce?
I want to move the position of add the cart, below the quantity.
Such like:
first line: price
second line: quantity
third line: add to the cart
please view the picture: https://snipboard.io/u7BXLU.jpg
I have tried many php but no effect.
Does anyone know how I can change it?
What I want is below picture
Regards,
Mavis

Add this code into your functions.php
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'move_add_to_cart_after_quantity', 35 );
function move_add_to_cart_after_quantity() {
global $product;
echo '<div class="woocommerce-product-details__quantity">';
    woocommerce_quantity_input( array(
    'min_value'   => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_min', $product->get_min_purchase_quantity(), $product ),
    'max_value'   => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_max', $product->get_max_purchase_quantity(), $product ),
    'input_value' => isset( $_POST['quantity'] ) ? wc_stock_amount( wp_unslash( $_POST['quantity'] ) ) : $product->get_min_purchase_quantity(),
    ) );
echo '</div>';

echo '<div class="woocommerce-product-details__button-wrapper">';
    echo '<button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt">' . esc_html( $product->single_add_to_cart_text() ) . '</button>';
echo '</div>';

}


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Thank you for your answer! It works!! There is a problem, [add to cart] and [quantity] is too close, and how to change length of the box of [add to cart] ?

You didn't added the page url, so its hard to help you. You can use custom css to move buttons (also add !importnat  in your css)  Example: .add-to-cart: margin: 15px 0px  0px 10px !importnat; (margin: top, right, bottom, left )
